# Extbase - Store Domain Objects into TYPO3 session

Tags: session, serialization, typo3, extbase

Usually it is possible to put any domain object into session ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user) as they get automatically serialized and deserialized correctly. But in some cases this fails (i suppose caused by circurlar references or the serialized data exceeds the limit of the database blob field).

I found a better approach, converting the domain objects to integer "ids" on serialization and getting the real domain objects back from repository on deserialization:

```
class PutMeIntoSession implements \Serializable {

    protected $project = null;

    public function getProject() {
        return $this->project;
    }

    public function setProject(\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\Project $project = NULL) {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function serialize() {
        $serialized = serialize(array(
            'project' =>  $this->project ? $this->project->getUid() : 0
        ));
        return $serialized;
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
        $this->project = $objectManager->get(ProjectRepository::class)->findByUid($unserialized['project']);
    }

}
```

This seems to work fine. But i don't know if there are smarter ways to achieve this or if there are any possible problems with my approach?

Comment: Since you already got your Project Object and it costed you quite some resources to build it, why don't you put it into cache?

Comment: What do you mean concrete?